# I get smalldatetime error when formatting by date range using predicate builder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, predicate

In the personnel management system, I have the necessary parameters to filter. I'm using them with the linq dynamic core library. I'm passing all the filter parameters I receive into a single string predicate. I'm using String predicate with PredicateBuilder. If I don't use .api, I can sort by date, but when using API, it doesn't sort by date. apide gives smalldatetime conversion error. For example, I want to list those whose starting date is between September 12, 2020 and September 12, 2023, but it gives a conversion error. I tried many ways but I could not succeed. I'm giving my related classes below, I'm waiting for those who have ideas about how I can solve it.

**API layer:**

```
MemberController
[HttpPost("GetDataPaged")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetDataPagedAsync([FromBody] PageRequestDto pageRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                Expression<Func<Member, bool>> predicate;

                // Predicate vermezsek tüm veriyi çeker.
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageRequest.Predicate))
                {
                    predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Member>(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    predicate = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<Member, bool>(ParsingConfig.Default, false, pageRequest.Predicate);
                    
                }

                var result = await _serviceManager.Members.GetDataPagedAsync(predicate, pageRequest.PageIndex, pageRequest.Take, pageRequest.OrderBy);
                if (result == null)
                {
                    return CreateActionResultInstance(CustomResponseDto<string>.Fail(Messages.GeneralMessages.NotFound, 404));
                }

                var pagination = new PaginationApi<Member>()
                {
                    PageIndex = result.PageIndex,
                    pageSize = 25,
                    TotalPages = result.TotalPages,
                    TotalRecords = result.TotalRecords,
                    HasPreviousPage = result.HasPreviousPage,
                    HasNextPage = result.HasNextPage,
                    MyGridData = result
                };

                return CreateActionResultInstance(CustomResponseDto<PaginationApi<Member>>.Success(pagination, 200));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return CreateActionResultInstance(CustomResponseDto<string>.Fail(ex.Message, 400));
            }
        }
```

---

**Core layer**

```
 public async Task<PaginatedList<TEntity>> GetDataPagedAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, int pageIndex, int take, string orderBy)
        {

            var query = context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

            if (predicate != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(predicate);
            }

            var count = await query.CountAsync(); //it gives the error here, it falls into the catch block in the api layer
        }
```

---

**UI layer**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index
    (string? Date1 = "", string? Date2 = "",)
        {
            string predicateString = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
            {
                predicateString = $"NameSurname.Contains(\"{SearchText}\")";
            }
            
    DateTime? parsedDate1 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Date1) ? DateTime.Parse(Date1) : (DateTime?)null;
            DateTime? parsedDate2 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Date2) ? DateTime.Parse(Date2) : (DateTime?)null;
            if (parsedDate1.HasValue && parsedDate2.HasValue)
            {
                predicateString += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(predicateString) ? "" : " && ") + $"UserStartDate>=\"{parsedDate1.Value.ToString("s")}\" && UserStartDate<=\"{parsedDate2.Value.ToString("s")}\"";

            }
            var apiService = _apiServiceFactory.Create<Member, JObject>();
            var dataObject = await apiService.GetDataPaged(pageRequest);
        }
```

---

The place where it gives a smalldatetime error is in the following lines in the API:

> _serviceManager.Members.GetDataPagedAsync(predicate, pageRequest.PageIndex, pageRequest.Take, pageRequest.OrderBy);

Should I follow a different path to sort by date or are there places in the code that I need to edit? I also want to make a sort for `UserStartDate` field and this field is of `smalldatetime` type in SQL.
When the count variable in the core layer works, it enters the catch block in the api and gives a smalldatetime conversion error.

Comment: You should try boiling that code down to a readable [mre] to get a higher likelihood of a response. Get a simple query that repros the issue

Comment: transmit dates in this format in ur api
 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'

Comment: I am passing the date string as you said to the app, but after parsing it below, it restores the formatted date value

else
                {
                    predicate = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<Member, bool>(ParsingConfig.Default, false, pageRequest.Predicate);
                    
                }